# Lazy State monad in Idris

Tags: lazy-evaluation, idris

I am trying to generate a Stream value in a monadic context. For example, the following code hangs in Idris (or segfaults):

```
import Control.Monad.State

count : State Int (Stream Int)
count = do
      x <- get
      put (x+1)
      t <- count
      pure (x :: t)

stream : List Int
stream = take 10 (evalState count 0)
```

However, similar code works in Haskell, using the lazy state monad:

```
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

count :: State Int [Int]
count = do
      x <- get
      put (x+1)
      t <- count
      return (x : t)

stream :: [Int]
stream = take 10 (evalState count 0)
```

This is probably because of lazy pattern matching used in the bind operation of the state monad in Haskell. Is there something similar in Idris?

Comment: You would probably have to make your own lazy state monad. Idris has Lazy and Inf.